# How to load Disks on the fly rather than on boot

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I have an i5 4590 and 4Gb of RAM. On linux, the experience is smooth, it boots in 5 secs every things is cool. However, windows takes ages to load, and sometime immediately after boot, it won't run any program or open task manager, the only thing I can do is Hard Reset. The last straw is that for daily usage, my previous PC was faster than my current (AMD Athlon XP+)!

So I wanted to know more. Why would windows be slower than linux, or slower than the same windows (with same AV) on an i3.

Well, I tried just to see to disable 4 sata ports (which were plugged into HDDs) in BIOS to leave only two (one for w7, one for linux).

As far as I can tell, it looked better. And it makes sense because linux does not mount HDDs unless I need them. **Is there a way to mount them on the fly** like linux does ?

Comment: *"windows takes ages to load"* -- Actually you're asking an XY question.  You should run `msconfig`, and examine what programs and services are executed at startup.  You probably have a boatload.  Programs that access the Internet searching for updates can bog down Windows at startup.

Comment: I have only 9 programs. Will try soluto :)

Comment: Nine is three times more than what I have on this PC, and none of those three go searching for updates.

Comment: They are utorrent, hsmgr, hsmgr, avast av (with auto update disabed), stikynot, networx, Cmicnfg dynamic link library, realtek audio manager.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can tell, it looked better. And it makes sense because linux does not mount HDDs unless I need them.

The second sentence in this statement is incorrect. I don't see you mentioning anywhere which specific Linux distribution you're using, but it's probably safe to say that any desktop- or server-oriented Linux distribution mounts all file systems listed in /etc/fstab not marked as `noauto` on boot. Mounting file systems is a cheap operation so there is no real reason not to do it that way, except for removable media. I have approaching a *hundred* file systems on my Linux system, most on rotational media which means I'd likely be IOPS bound, and mounting them during boot takes something like 2-3 seconds, maybe five seconds tops. Which, with some knowledge of the process involved, seems quite reasonable and even fast. *Mounting file systems does not take any significant amount of time.*

> Is there a way to mount them on the fly like linux does ?

Since the premise of your question is wrong, I could actually disregard this part. That said, you **can** remove the drive letter assignment for the relevant partitions through the Computer Management tool provided by Windows, which will force you to reassign drive letters any time you want to access those partitions from within Windows.

It sounds as though even if you could save some small amount of time per boot, it's going to take much longer to go in and make that change repeatedly. Let alone that doing so manually is error-prone and is likely to lead to frustration in short order.

It is certainly possible that you saw a startup speed improvement in Windows when unplugging the drives, but **that improvement was almost certainly for some secondary reason.** Even a full scan of the root directory of a partition should literally take on the order of a second or less, and should be done by a background thread unless you are doing something that actively requires knowledge of the root directory contents.

If your Windows installation is having performance issues during the boot process that were seemingly at least partially resolved by making physical hard disks unavailable to Windows, then I recommend using the tools provided, and asking questions about the tools provided, for diagnosing I/O performance issues. Focus on fixing the source of the problem, rather than band-aiding over the symptoms.

Comment: I use ubuntu, and my disks are NOT mounted unless I need them. I will try to disagnose windows. Any recommended tools ?

Comment: @Vinz243 As we sometimes say, extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. For example [the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki indicates autofs is not installed by default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) and even when it is installed must be manually configured. You could provide this evidence by editing your question to include the output of running `mount` in a terminal before and after accessing one of those partitions; the data would show which hypothesis is correct in this case. (That said, I still stand by the statement that the performance impact should be trivial at most.)

Comment: Perhaps on HDD is slowing everything ? I don't know. Ill send the output ASAP

Comment: @Vinz243 If you don't know, then rather than presupposing a cause and asking how to do something which you believe will fix that specific issue, it is often better to describe the situation in as much detail as you reasonably can, and ask how to determine the specific cause of the behavior you are seeing, such that you can later formulate a better question on how to rectify the problem. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730) for some discussion on this phenomenon.

Comment: You're right I still have this problem :(  will try zhpdiag, avast and malwarebyte. here is the result of mount command under ubuntu http://pastebin.com/fVprPSBE (but I removed most disks)